# How to fix the code so it can run 5 times with for-loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, random, numbers

I'm trying to run this 5 times with five different numbers (randomly, see int x), it runs without any problem with 1 attempt.
I tried to add a for-loop (lines with //) and it became a mess.
What can I do to fix it?

Example Result: --> What can I do to fix it?

```
My code will print the following:
          Trial       Number of Elements      Search Key    ....
            1                65536               123 (random) ....
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - --  - -- - - - - - - - - 
I want to become the following: 
  Trial       Number of Elements      Search Key
    1                65536               123 (random)
    2                65536               1234 (random)
    3                65536               1123 (random)
    4                65536               11234 (random)
    5                65536               15234 (random)
```

Comment: what do you mean by "it became a mess"?

Comment: All numbers I got makes no sense. For example, my number should be between 1-65536 but I will get numbers that are way higher that 65536. You can run it, it works fine with 1 attempt (meaning not using the my for-loop and I commented it out).

Comment: Which number? compareCount will continue to grow as it isn never reset. Can you show an example of the output which you think is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the case when result = -1 (when values is not present in the array)

so when result = -1
you are trying to access arr[result - 1] i.e. arr[-2], which is clearly an invalid index

```java
import java.util.Random;

class BinarySearch {
    private int compareCount;


    int binarySearch(int arr[], int l, int r, int x) { 
       
        if (r >= l) { 
            int mid = l + (r - l) / 2; 
              
            compareCount++;
            if (arr[mid] == x) 
                return mid; 
    
            compareCount++;
            if (arr[mid] > x) 
                return binarySearch(arr, l, mid - 1, x); 

            return binarySearch(arr, mid + 1, r, x); 
        }
        return -1; 
    } 

    
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        

        for (int i = 0; i<5;i++) {
            
            BinarySearch ob = new BinarySearch();     
            int[] arr = new Random().ints(65536, 1, 65536 + 1).sorted().toArray();
            
            int n = arr.length; 

            Random rand = new Random();
            int max_range = 65536;
            
            int x = rand.nextInt(max_range); // generate a random number between 1-65536
            System.out.println(x);

            int result = ob.binarySearch(arr, 0, n - 1, x);
            
            String isFound = "N";
            if (result != -1)
                isFound = "Y";
            

            int N = 65536; 
            int expect = (int)(Math.log(N) / Math.log(2)) + 1; 
            
              
          if(result != -1){
                int right_index = 0;
                if(result+1 == max_range) {
                    right_index = arr[result];
                }
                else {
                    right_index = arr[result + 1];
                }

                int left_index = 0;
                if(result == 0) {
                    left_index = arr[0];
                }
                else {
                    left_index = arr[result + 1];
                }

                System.out.println
                ("   Trial    "  +   "   Number of Elements   " +  "   Search Key   " + "   Left Index  " + "   Right Index  " + "    Found/Not Found   " + " Expected Comparision  " + "   Acutal Comparsion   "   + "\n" 
                +"     " + (i + 1) + "              "  +  arr.length +  "              " + x  +   "         " + left_index + "      " + right_index +  "              " + isFound  + "            " + expect + "                   "+  ob.compareCount);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println
                ("   Trial    "  +   "   Number of Elements   " +  "   Search Key   " + "   Left Index  " + "   Right Index  " + "    Found/Not Found   " + " Expected Comparision  " + "   Acutal Comparsion   "   + "\n" 
                +"     "+(i+ 1)+"              "  +  arr.length +  "              " + x  +   "         " + "NOT FOUND" + "      " + "NOT FOUND" +  "              " + isFound  + "            " + expect + "                   "+  ob.compareCount);
            }
            
     }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: What can I do to make trail become 1 2 3 4 5?

Comment: I have updated the code! we can use value of i in our string

Comment: If your problem is resolved you can accept the solution

Comment: You should also handle result == max_range to avoid another IndexOutOfBounds.

Comment: ob.binarySearch() will never return result = max_range. right? So do we need to handle it?

Comment: It returns the index of an random number in a random array. So the result can also result in the start or end of the array which will lead to IOFB Exception when accessing index-1 or index+1 as left/right elements in the sysout.

Comment: Can also happen if the index == 0, means it returns the first element in the array. The sysout can be adapted with ternary operator to avoid the IndexOutOfBounds. See my answer "fix the logging like this".

Answer (score 0):

Since your BinarySearch object contains a "compareCount" I think you added the for loop one line to late... Each run might create a new BinarySearch() to reset the compareCount.

So move the loop up.

Also your left/right index can produce index out of bounds if you find

- the first element
- the last element
- no element

You could fix the logging like this:

- (result > 0 ? arr[result - 1] : "nout found")
- (result < max_range ? arr[result + 1] : "not found")